# A Particular Metric: $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that the metric $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ is indeed a metric. Here
$$d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max\{\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert, \lvert y_1-y_2\rvert\}.$$

I've got everything up to the triangle inequality, and I've got
$$\max\{\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert , \lvert y_1-y_2\rvert\}\leq \max\{\lvert x_1-x_3\rvert , \lvert y_1-y_3\rvert\}+\max\{\lvert x_2-x_3\rvert , \lvert y_2-y_3\rvert\}$$
written down, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Show that $\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert \leqslant d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)) + d_2((x_3,y_3),(x_2,y_2))$ and the same for the $y$ coordinates.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me...

Comment: Maybe this becomes easier by generalizing. Assume you have some set $X$ with a metric $d$ and some set $Y$ with a metric $d'$. Now build a metric $d_2$ on $X \times Y$ by $d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \max(d(x_1,x_2),d'(y_1,y_2))$.

Comment: @Trancot, $|x_1-x_2| \le |x_1-x_3| + |x_2-x_3| \le \dots$

Comment: You know the triangle equality $|a+b|\le |a| + |b|$ and you also know that $a\le \max(a,b)$ and that $a\le c \land b\le c\implies max(a,b)\le c$

Comment: Ha ha ha... R2D2 $\leadsto$ $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$

Comment: Wait, why is R2D2 called R2D2?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You know the triangle inequality for the usual metric on $\Bbb R$:

$$|x_1-x_2|\le|x_1-x_3|+|x_3-x_2|\;.$$

Apply that separately to the $x$-coordinates and the $y$-coordinates of $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle,\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$, and $\langle x_3,y_3\rangle$. Then use the fact that if $a\le b$ and $c\le d$, then $\max\{a,c\}\le\max\{b,d\}$. (You should of course justify that fact.)